# Circular dependency in AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The following is the template.yaml for the lambda function. I'm trying to add permissions to access the `status` database. However, it needs the database to exist and vice versa, and so I get a circular dependency error with `DynamoDBIamPolicy`. How can I resolve this?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  friendTeachers:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: friendTeachers/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 15
  status:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    Properties:
      TableName: status
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: screenName
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: screenName
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
  # A policy is a resource that states one or more permssions. It lists actions, resources and effects.
  DynamoDBIamPolicy: 
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    DependsOn: status
    Properties:
      PolicyName: lambda-dynamodb
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - dynamodb:DescribeTable
              - dynamodb:Query
              - dynamodb:Scan
              - dynamodb:GetItem
              - dynamodb:PutItem
              - dynamodb:UpdateItem
              - dynamodb:DeleteItem
              - dynamodb:batchWriteItem
            Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/status
      Roles:
        - Ref: IamRoleLambdaExecution
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a role where you specify that the lambda service can *AssumeRole*. The role needs to have a policy associated that specifies the operations that can be done in the DynamoDb table. Find below an example that shows what you are trying to accomplish:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  friendTeachersFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: LambdaCodeBucket
        S3Key:
          Ref: LambdaCodePath
      Handler: friendTeachers/index.handler
      Runtime: "nodejs6.10"
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 15
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - friendTeachersExecutionRole
        - Arn
  friendTeachersExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: UseDBPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - dynamodb:DescribeTable
              - dynamodb:Query
              - dynamodb:Scan
              - dynamodb:GetItem
              - dynamodb:PutItem
              - dynamodb:UpdateItem
              - dynamodb:DeleteItem
              - dynamodb:batchWriteItem
            Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/status
  APIDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: status
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: screenName
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: screenName
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Note that Code.S3Bucket and Code.S3Key are defined as parameters. When you create the stack in AWS Console you can specify the path there.

Comment: You're right with what you're saying. However, he is using the [serverless application model](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md). Here it's not required for a Lambda Function that you set a S3 bucket for the `Code` property. You can also point to a local artifact using `CodeUri` and prepare your stack by using `aws cloudformation package`. Furthermore, it's also possible to declare the policies inline [see example](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction).

Comment: @shesse is right, i don't need a bucket (or the Parameters section). Please remove that part/clarify your answer and i'll accept your answer... it otherwise works.

Comment: @UAvalos I missed that part. I've amended the answer.